# Adding color to models

Tags: materials, objects

I created a small model of a building, then tried to add some color. But when I apply the color the "entire" model is affected instead of just the highlighted area of the model. I want to use multiple colors on that model. Different color depending on the model section/area. I can't get this done.

Not sure if this will help. Last attempt.
Clicked "Edit Mode". (next option) Textures. then scrolled to the circle icon right of the triangle. Tried using color from the "Diffuse" and "Specular" sections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go into edit mode
2. Select the faces you want for one color , And click the + button in  the materials section

[image]

This will apply the color to all faces , Next click on another face , click the + button , and click "Assign" this will give the selected face the new material

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you. I just tried your suggestion and it worked. I wasn't setting/assigning the materials. No wonder I wasn't getting anywhere lol.

Comment: great! , Could you click the Tick so everyone knows the answer is correct? Thanks :) , im glad it helped

Comment: Sure... where do I click? (I'm new here, don't know how the site works yet) sorry.